# Auto/Manual Select Peers As Group Owner When Group Owner leaves the Group

Tags: android, wifi-direct

Hi i would like know if it is possible to automatically/manually select the other peers to become the Group Owner , once the Group owner decide to leave the group.

For example:

Phone 1 , Phone  2 are both connected to Phone 3(Group Owner).
Phone 3 leaves the Group.

Either Phone 1 or Phone 2 will now become the GO.

My idea: Maybe when the Group owner leaves, we detect it by using OnDisconnect()? Then inside the function i do some code that will pass the value config.groupOwnerIntent =15; to the other peers? Hurmmm I really need help on this . Thank you very much.

Comment: As far as I understand the API, it does not provide this kind of automated stuff. Thus you do need to design logic for selecting the GO, or simply re-start the connection establishments, and let the devices select GO.